# onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Trying to make a image based button that will change a image on the page

Here is the code I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function nextimg()
{
alert("clicked")
document.getElementById("image").src="images/gallery/gallery-2.jpg";
}

</script>
<div class="gallery">
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/lt_arrow_dark.png"/></td>
<td><img id="image" src="images/gallery/gallery-1.jpg"/></td>
<td><img onclick="nextimg()" src="images/rt_arrow_dark.png" height="55" width="24"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the image. Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: What does the console say? Any ideas?

Comment: I created a fiddle and it seems to be working fine. Could there possibly be something else causing the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/Ep3ze/2/. You may want to install firebug for firefox to check if there are any javascript errors that are being thrown. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Seems like I cant click on that area at all I changed the onclick to a link and I cant click on that either. Could it be something I did in the CSS?

Comment: possibly update my jsfiddle with your css

Comment: stops working with the css....

Comment: with the css http://jsfiddle.net/Ep3ze/4/

Comment: I found your problem. Check out my answer below.

Comment: Found it z-index was at fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `z-index` of -2 in your css.

```
.gallery {
    background-color:#090909;
    position:relative;
    top:60px;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ep3ze/6/)

Answer (score 2):

```
alert("clicked") ; //missing something
```

Comment: That wont prevent it from working. Semicolons are not always required in javascript.

Comment: still does not work, I don't think its the script as the <img onclick="nextimg()" src="images/rt_arrow_dark.png" height="55" width="24"/> line works elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code verbatim into a HTML file on my machine and it pops up the "clicked!" alert in both Chrome and Firefox. Are you sure you don't have JavaScript disabled or something? What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Javascript into head and the other part of the code into body, enveloped in HTML got it to work for me on Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    windown.onload = function() {
       function nextimg() {
          alert("clicked")
          document.getElementById("image").src="images/gallery/gallery-2.jpg";
       }
    }

</script>
```